# Refresh parent dropdownlist from popup in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, popupwindow

I have a dropdwnlist control in my parent page - ASP.NET C#, on click of button there is a popup opening to add new value to the control.

[+]

In PopUp page - Save button , I have the following code :

```
Response.Write("<script>opener.loadOptionLandlord('" + stid  + "','" + strLandlorconn_dbame + "');</script>");
Response.Write("<script>window.close();</script>");
```

where loadOptionLandlord is a function in my parent page :

```
function loadOptionLandlord(val,txt)
        {
            var opt = document.createElement('<option value="'+ val +'">');
            opt.innerText = txt;
            var sCtrl = document.getElementById('<%= ddlLandlord.ClientID %>');

            sCtrl.options[sCtrl.options.length] = new Option(txt, val, false, true);

        }
```

The value is being saved to the database and the popup window is closing , but the newly added data is not refreshing in the dropdownlist.
This is working for IE, but not for Chrome.

Please help ..

Comment: Only the dropdownlist controls needs to be refreshed

Comment: check your console did u got any error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change your `loadOptionLandlord` as below**

```
function loadOptionLandlord(val,txt)
        {
            var opt = document.createElement("option");            
            var sCtrl = document.getElementById('<%= ddlLandlord.ClientID %>').options.add(opt);
            opt.text = txt;
            opt.value = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you check this function ?

```
function loadOptionLandlord(val,txt)
        {
            // Those create element not needed and its a wrong 
            // because you directly add option to select
            //var opt = document.createElement('<option value="'+ val +'">');
           // opt.innerText = txt;
            var sCtrl = document.getElementById('<%= ddlLandlord.ClientID %>');

            sCtrl.options[sCtrl.options.length] = new Option(txt, val, false, true);

        }
```

here is sample js to add option on drop-down [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/maxiwidele/2/)

Comment: no its not working..actually the same code is working in IE, but not chrome.